# Why do I get an error when creating a sequence in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

```sql
SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name 
FROM information_schema.sequences 
ORDER BY sequence_name
```

The result is

```
sequence_schema,sequence_name
public,coin_engraver_id_seq
public,coinside_id_seq
auth,refresh_tokens_id_seq
```

There is no 'country_id_seq' there. So why then do I get an error when trying to create one?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "country_id_seq"
```

The error being
`Error in query (7): ERROR: relation "country_id_seq" already exists`

Comment: It says "relation", not "sequence". Is there any chance you have another object (table, view, etc) with that name in your schema?

Comment: @Bergi I dumped all data from all tables in the information schema and searched for that. I found nothing.

Comment: Try dumping the `pg_catalog` instead of the `information_schema`. Or also try to `pg_dump --schema-only` your database

Comment: What was it that didn't show up in the information schema?

Comment: That seq didn't show up. I now need to go figure out why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a relation (table, view, sequence, materialized view, index or composite type) with the same name in the same schema. If the `information_schema` doesn't show that object, it may well be because you can only see objects in `information_schema` if you have some permissions on them.